# Azure Function : async method and output parameters

Tags: c#, queue, azure-functions, message-queue

I want to use output queue in my azure function. I get an example code from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/queue-storage

```
[FunctionName("BasicQueueOutput")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
                       TraceWriter log,
                       [Queue("101functionsqueue",Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] out string queueMessage)
{
    log.Info("101 Azure Function Demo - Storage Queue output");

    queueMessage = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
}
```

it works fine for sync method, but in my case it's async method:

```
    [FunctionName("FunctionRegisterDomain")]
    public async static Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("domain-registation", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]DomainForRegistration queueItem,
        [Queue("domain-add-to-office365", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]out DomainForRegistration outputQueue,
        ILogger log)
```

and I get an error:

> Async methods cannot have ref, in or out parameters

of course, I can do it :

```
    [Queue("domain-add-to-office365", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]CloudQueue outputQueue,
```

and then use it:

```
await outputQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueItem)));
```

but I would like to do it with bindings to queue message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `IAsyncCollector<T>` to change from out param to that. Instead of “out string message” you change to `ICollector<string> messages` or `IAsyncCollector<string>` and add you message to the collection in the body.